# Integral of $\frac{1}{x}$ from $0$ to $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis

What is the value of the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} \, \mathbb{1}_{x >0} \, dx \quad ?$$

I get: $\log(x) |_{0}^{\infty}$.

From my textbook, it says this equals to infinity, but why? How can we rigorously argue that?

Comment: what is $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\log(x)$? What is $\lim\limits_{t\to 0^+}\log (t)$?

Comment: The former is pos inf, the latter is neg inf, but then the integral of the original expression should be undefined... not infinity... thats my problem

Comment: Your mistake is thinking it should be $\infty-\infty$, when it is $\infty - (-\infty) = \infty+\infty = \infty$.

Comment: Is $1_{x>0}$ a characteristic function (value is either zero or one) type thing?

Comment: Your title has the interval of integration go from $0$ to infinity, yet the integral in question is from -infinity to infinity. Which interval is it? And what is $1_{x>0}$?

Comment: $1_{x>0}$ is an indicator function. It equals $1$ on the set indicated by the subscript and is $0$ otherwise.

Comment: @Accelerator the integrand addresses the interval of integration.

Comment: @user3180 some textbooks treat this topic differently. It isn’t formal to say the integral is equal to infinity, but it *is* intuitively the correct answer (it conveys the behavior of the integral which is more than saying that the integral DNE does).

Comment: $\log(x)|_0^{\infty} = \log(\infty) - \log 0 $ but $\log 0 = -\infty$ (if we are going to allow ourselves to abuse notation like that) so $\log(\infty)-\log = \infty - (-\infty) =\infty + \infty = \infty $.   Kind of weird to rewrite it as $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac 1x 1_{x>0}dx$ rather than simply $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac 1x dx$.  If we don't have that restriction that $x > 0$ we'd clearly have $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx = 0$ for any odd function $f$.

Comment: It is improper integral. Make it proper. Then take limit.

Comment: Do not say "$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx = 0$ for any odd function $f$."  Instead say 
"$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx = 0$ for any odd function $f$ such that the integral converges."

Comment: The harmonic series can be used as an underestimate for this integral and it is easy to see that it diverges to infinity.

Comment: By the definition of an improper interval, $$\begin{align}\int_0^\infty \frac {dx}x &= \int_0^1 \frac {dx}x + \int_1^\infty \frac {dx}x\\&= \lim_{a \to 0+}\int_a^1 \frac {dx}x + \lim_{b \to \infty}\int_1^b \frac {dx}x\\ &=  \lim_{a \to 0+}(-\log a) +  \lim_{b \to \infty} \log b\end{align}$$ Now both limits **diverge** to $+\infty$ as does their sum. That is what they mean by saying $\int_0^\infty \frac {dx}x = \infty$.